# How can i improve mariadb performacne

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, query-optimization

Hello i have following problem. I want to query data from our mariadb.
Somtimes the query is very fast ~10-20 Seconds and sometimes the query is very ~5-30 minutes.

But i do not have an idea why the query sometimes is slow.

I hope you can help me.

Table:

```
        CREATE TABLE `values_original` (
        `dp_name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
        `stime` TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(3),
        `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
        `status64` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
        `manager` INT(11) NOT NULL,
        `value_number` DOUBLE(22,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `value_text` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
        PRIMARY KEY (`stime`, `dp_name`, `status64`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `values_original_dp_name_index` (`dp_name`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `values_original_stime_index` (`stime`) USING BTREE,
        INDEX `values_original_dp_name_stime_index` (`dp_name`, `stime`) USING BTREE
    )
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    ;
```

myini:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=D:/xxx/MariaDB/data
port=3306
innodb_buffer_pool_size=26G
#innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=1G
#innodb-buffer-pool-instances=16
event_scheduler=ON
tmpdir=D:/xxx/MariaDB/tmp

query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=10M
query_cache_limit=256k
```

The query:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(stime,'+00:00',@@session.time_zone), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000')) AS daytime, 
       dp_name, avg(value_number) AS value_avg, sum(value_number) AS value_sum, 
       min(value_number) AS value_min, max(value_number) AS value_max, value_text 
    FROM values_original  
    WHERE dp_name in ('a1',....,'a50') 
     AND stime >= TIMESTAMP('2021-12-26 23:00:00.000') 
     AND stime < TIMESTAMP('2021-12-30 23:00:00.000') 
GROUP BY dp_name, daytime;
```

the result of the explain:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |      table      | type  |                                             possible_keys                                             |   key   | key_len | ref | rows |                    Extra                     |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | values_original | range | PRIMARY,values_original_dp_name_index,values_original_stime_index,values_original_dp_name_stime_index | PRIMARY |     208 |   0 |    1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+-----+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Run `explain select ...` and add the ouput of that to your question

Comment: the result of the explain: "id";"select_type";"table";"type";"possible_keys";"key";"key_len";"ref";"rows";"Extra"
"1";"SIMPLE";"values_original";"range";"PRIMARY,values_original_dp_name_index,values_original_stime_index,values_original_dp_name_stime_index";"PRIMARY";"208";\0;"1";"Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"

Comment: I think you may use `GROUP BY stime, dp_name`.

Comment: if i use stime in the group by i could not build day values in the query. because of that i use "daytime". it is converted from stime (hour, minute, second set to 0)

Comment: i recognized that the first query of the day is slow. the second call is fast. does mariadb clear the buffer/cache periodically

Comment: *if i use stime in the group by i could not build day values in the query.* ?? why? `daytime` is scalar expression which includes `stime` value and runtime constants processed by deterministic functions only. Its usage must eliminate `Using temporary; Using filesort`... test. PS. `value_text` in output list is wrong (when ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled the query will fail).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have thousands or even millions of rows to scan to run the query?

Normalize this so you have only, say, a 2-byte `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` in this table.

```
    `dp_name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
```

Perhaps you don't really want the value rounded to 0 decimal places?  Change to `DOUBLE` (16 significant digits) or perhaps `FLOAT` (7 significant digits):

```
    `value_number` DOUBLE(22,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

Is the value really NULLable?  If not, say `NOT NULL`.  (Ditto for other columns.)

What kind of text is this?  Why is it here?  Can it be normalized?

```
    `value_text` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
```

Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE "values_original" \G`  The size is of interest.

For lots of data, the solution is to build and maintain a "summary table".  It would have daily (or perhaps hourly) subtotals.  (Use (sum of sums) / sum of counts) to get an overall average.)

More discussion:  [*summary tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

The `EXPLAIN` shows an estimated "1 row".  That disagrees with "5-30 minutes"; please explain.  Perhaps you did the `EXPLAIN` against a `stime` range that had very few rows?

Answer (score 0):

The main performance problem is the inappropriate use of a IN with too much values :

```
dp_name in ('a1',....,'a50')
```

If you have really 50 items in the IN list, you should rewrite the query and use a temporary table to store the 50 values and join it with values_original. Of course the temp table must have a primary key on the column storing your 'an' values.

Also your GROUP BY clause is inconsistent giving false results (this is specific to MySQL, no other RDBMS would accept such a query).

Comment: @MichaelS . . . I don't downvote answers, but this one is not correct.  There is no problem in MySQL with having 50 constant values in an `IN` list -- and particularly in MySQL, because it optimizes the search using a binary search.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that the approach I'm about to suggest is much more cumbersome.

But, with the right indexes, how fast is this query?

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(stime, '+00:00', @@session.time_zone), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00.000')) AS daytime, 
       dp_name, avg(value_number) AS value_avg, sum(value_number) AS value_sum, 
       min(value_number) AS value_min, max(value_number) AS value_max, value_text 
    FROM values_original  
    WHERE dp_name = 'a1' AND
          stime >= TIMESTAMP('2021-12-26 23:00:00.000') 
          stime < TIMESTAMP('2021-12-30 23:00:00.000') 
    GROUP BY dp_name, daytime;
```

The right index is `values_original(dp_name, sttime, value__number)`.  This index should make looking up the rows used for the `GROUP BY` quite fast.  The first two keys are the critical columns for the index.  The last just allows the index to cover the query, so access to the data pages is not needed.

If this works, you can concatenate 50 versions of this query together using `UNION ALL`.  Combined they will each use the index.  The result set is the `UNION ALL` of those result sets.

Note that the most recent versions of MySQL support skip-scan index searches, which would allow the index to work on your version of the query.  That would still be a little bit slower, because 50 aggregations is usually faster than aggregations on 50X the data -- but that difference should be pretty minimal.

Answer (score -1):

Hy Thank You for your many answers.

The "Show Table Status" query shows the following result:

| "Name" | "Engine" | "Version" | "Row_format" | "Rows" | "Avg_row_length" | "Data_length" | "Max_data_length" | "Index_length" | "Data_free" | "Auto_increment" | "Create_time" | "Update_time" | "Check_time" | "Collation" | "Checksum" | "Create_options" | "Comment" | "Max_index_length" | "Temporary" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "values_original" | "InnoDB" | "10" | "Dynamic" | "266774883" | "124" | "33335230464" | "0" | "51529121792" | "7340032" |  | "2020-12-14 20:29:16" | "2021-01-11 20:25:07" |  | "latin1_swedish_ci" |  |  |  | "0" | "N" |

At the moment i try to reorganize or modify the table. smaller varchars and so on.

Im also in progress to aggreagate the data into a new table.
i think this should be the best solution i our case.

Answer (score -1):

I'm on my end.

i created a new aggregated/summary table

```sql
CREATE TABLE values_original_minute (
    dp_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    stime TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(3),
    value_avg DOUBLE(14,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    value_sum DOUBLE(14,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    value_min DOUBLE(14,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    value_max DOUBLE(14,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    value_text VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (stime, dp_name) USING BTREE,
    INDEX values_original_dp_name_index (dp_name) USING BTREE,
    INDEX values_original_stime_index` (stime) USING BTREE,
    INDEX values_original_dp_name_stime_index (dp_name, stime) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

i aggregated all data from values_original into one minute steps.

It saved ~100.000.000 rows but if i try to query data. The first call of the query needs ~30 minutes. The second call is fast.